# Import Data from .csv to SQL Server using File Upload in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, csv

I have an .csv file which I upload it through a `FileUpload` control and I want to transfer the whole data from that csv file into a SQL Server database table, but I have some problems in my code:

```
 DataTable tblReadCSV = new DataTable();
    tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("EmailId");
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fupEmails.PostedFile.FileName);
    fupEmails.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Contacts/" + path));
    path = Server.MapPath("~/Contacts/" + path);
    TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(path);
    csvParser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
    //csvParser.ReadLine();
    while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
        tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(fields.Equals("Email"));
    }
    string connection = @"Data Source=ANURAG-PC; Initial Catalog=MailServer; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=sa; Password=anurag";
    string strSql = "Insert into EmailData(EmailId) Values(@Email)";
    SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connection);
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText=strSql;
    cmd.Connection=con;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email",SqlDbType.NVarChar,250,"Email");
    SqlDataAdapter daAdapter=new SqlDataAdapter();
    daAdapter.InsertCommand=cmd;
    int result=daAdapter.Update(tblReadCSV);
    lblError.Text="Send Successfully";
```

and I'm getting error in the second last line

```
int result = daAdapter.Update(tblReadCSV);
```

and the error is

> The parameterized query '(@Email nvarchar(250))Insert into EmailData(EmailId) Values(@Ema' expects the parameter '@Email', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email",SqlDbType.NVarChar,250,"EmailId");
```

The name of the column you added to the `DataTable` was `EmailId`, not `Email`.

Comment: Thnk you Michael i can you please help me for one more thing,in the following two lines-
 string[] fields = csvParser.ReadFields();
 tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(fields.Equals("Email"));
fields contains list of Headings of csv files now i just want only Email field how can i achieve thi, above line for this is not working...

Comment: @user3071613, comments isn't going to be the right approach here. Just detail the other question as another question.

Comment: ok michael i have added it as another question, kindly answer that question